# Two output file names resolved to the same output after changing form icon?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, resources, resx

So I know the usual fix for this error is to delete the extra .resx file that was created when you renamed a form or something else on your application.. But I haven't created/renamed any forms, and I don't see any obvious double .resx files.. This all happened after choosing an.ico file for the icon, that's it.

EDIT:

Well I had 2 .resx files that maybe have been about the same form fDesigner.resx and fMain.resx, the last one which was created an hour ago, I deleted it, but I'm STILL getting the same error, isn't there a file that references the .resx files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh well I found it, might as well answer it myself as well.. There should be a .vbproj file on your application directory, for VB.NET, I'm sure other languages have it different. But you have to edit this, whether you deleted your extra .resx or not:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="yourMmainForm.resx">
  <DependentUpon>yourMainForm.vb</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

In my case Designer.resx was already dependent upon my Main form so even after I deleted the file the duplicate was still there, ok now it's fixed.

Comment: Unload the project, right click on it, edit the .vbproj. Then set it back as startup project (if it was)